# Box2D functions are not found in manual

Tags: box2d

I have seen the following code in cocos2d-x 3 tests:

```
m_world->SetWarmStarting(settings->enableWarmStarting > 0);
m_world->SetContinuousPhysics(settings->enableContinuous > 0);
m_world->SetSubStepping(settings->enableSubStepping > 0);
```

But in [Box2D manual](http://box2d.org/manual.pdf) cannot find what these functions do. Where I can get the info?

Comment: :) Yes, but I think the library functions should be somewhere documented. If so then I I can't find?

Comment: The header of the source code is commented: https://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/browse/trunk/Box2D/Box2D/Dynamics/b2World.h#144 However, it looks like these three functions are not intended to be documented, as they are "for testing".

Comment: I have seen the comments, but the don't say more than the function names itself. :)

Answer (score 3):

> m_world->SetWarmStarting(settings->enableWarmStarting > 0);

The `b2World::SetWarmStarting` method enables or disables the *warm starting* state of the `*m_world` instance. *Warm starting* means that impulse states (in per-step velocity constraint points and in joints) get assigned potentially non-zero values that are multiples of the step `dtRatio`. When *warm starting* is disabled, these are just simply set to zero.

To see this for yourself, you can do a search in the Box2D C++ code for the text `warmStarting` which is a field of the `b2TimeStep` class that's set from the world's `m_warmStarting` field (set from the quoted method).

> m_world->SetContinuousPhysics(settings->enableContinuous > 0);

The `b2World:: SetContinuousPhysics` method enables or disables continuous collision detection (CCD).

If CCD is disabled, dynamic bodies - even if they have been set to be *bullet* objects - will *tunnel* through any other body when their combined velocities put the objects on opposite sides of each other after the time of the time step. *Tunneling* means that bodies have passed through each other counter to what's expected of the physics of solid bodies. Depending on the shape, even being within the other object (even penetrating the other object) at the time of the time step can result in tunneling occurring. With CCD disabled, collision islands are only calculated for the point in time that the time step would put the world to.

If CCD is enabled, bodies that are *bullet* bodies or *static* bodies will get continuous collision detection performed on them and any objects they could potentially collide with. In this situation, the possible contacts within the time step with these special bodies are determined (call these the *CCD enabled contacts*) along with a computed time of impact (essentially a percentage of the current time step). These contacts get iterated over in order of their times of impact - the contacts with the soonest times getting dealt with before later times. Collision islands are created for appropriate contacts and then just like when CCD is disabled, those islands are resolved; except now these islands aren't collisions at the time step but rather the islands at each sub time point where it's determined that the contact would actually touch.

You can search for the text `m_continuousPhysics` in the Box2D C++ code to find the call to the `SolveTOI` method and trace that source to learn for yourself about Box2D CCD processing. Admittedly it took me a while reading and refactoring this code to recognize what I've explained herein but I believe my explanation is accurate and easier to understand than following the original Box2D C++ source code in the `SolveTOI` method (which itself is some 318 lines in the `b2World.cpp` file). Alternatively, you can look at the `World::SolveTOI` method in the `Box2D/Dynamics/World.cpp` file in [my fork of Box2D](https://github.com/louis-langholtz/Box2D).

> m_world->SetSubStepping(settings->enableSubStepping > 0);

The `b2World::SetSubStepping` method enables or disables *sub-stepping* in the continuous collision detection of the `b2World::Step` method.

With sub-stepping enabled, the `b2World::Step` method will return after every next *CCD enabled contact* is resolved, rather than work till all these within the entire time step are resolved. This provides an observer a way to see what's going on one *CCD enabled contact* at a time. Note that regular contact resolution doesn't occur again until every CCD enabled contact is dealt with for the particular time step.

Conceptually at least, disabling sub-stepping should be more performant. I think it's also more intuitively simple to call `b2World::Step` and expect that after each call, the given *time step* will have actually transpired in-so-far as the physics simulation is concerned (which isn't the case when sub-stepping is enabled).

To learn about this method for yourself, you can search for the text:  `m_subStepping`.